# Отправить запрос серверу и после получения ответа запустить Local Push уведомление Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Возможно ли отправить запрос через каждые опр секунд с приложения Flutter и после получения нужного ответа запустить Local Push уведомление на устройстве? Цель: хочу синхронизировать бэкенд с приложением Flutter и выводить Local Push при получении нужного ответа от бэкенда. (не хочу использовать какие либо другие сторонние сервисы).

Comment: насколько понимаю, тут реализация зависит от платформы. В Android можно сервис запилить, который будет работать в фоне... и для iOS тоже нужно будет написать какое-то количество нативного кода.

Comment: есть еще package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service возможно он в себе уже все что нужно содержит и решает ваши проблемы, но я его не пробовал еще

Comment: @МихаилРебров сейчас у меня через Webview сделан апк приложение (сайт -> апп), в нем имеется jquery код SetInterval который каждый раз отправляет запрос и если взамен получает нужный статус то происходит звуковое оповещение, проблема в том что если свернуть приложение и со стороны сервака придет нужный статус то звуковое оповещение не срабатывает пока приложение не развернуть обратно, не понимаю почему так ради всего этого и смотрю в сторону flutter